# Java version shipped with DB2 v11?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I can't seem to find any information of which Java version that will be used in the soon to be released DB2 V11.1. Does anyone else know?

Comment: The prerelease version that I saw some time ago had Java 8.

Comment: Thanx, that's a relief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Java version 1.8.0.
General availability date of Db2 LUW 11.1 is today by the way....